# pyfirmata stop servo control

Tags: python, firmata

I have a test script to verify my servo setup.  It works fine and ends but I still hear power going to the servos.  How do I stop this signal.

```
import pyfirmata

board = pyfirmata.Arduino('/dev/ttyACM0')
turret = board.get_pin('d:5:s')
left = board.get_pin('d:11:s')
right = board.get_pin('d:10:s')

right.write(90)
left.write(60)
time.sleep(3)
left.write(90)
time.sleep(3)
right.write(120)
time.sleep(3)
right.write(90)
time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to turn it off by switching values in parentheses back to 0.

```
right.write(0)
left.write(0)
```